# Passing arguements through main - Checking to see if a valid input

Tags: c++, g++, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

I'm trying to pass arguments through main, which works fine, I then check to see if the passed in argument contains the correct format/value. However, even if I pass through the correct format it still shows that there is something wrong, here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

/* Check if arguments are being passed through */ 

if(argc == 1){
    cout << endl << "--- ERROR ---" << endl;
    exit(0);
}

/* Check if the first argument contains the correct data */
string file_name = argv[1];

/* Handle operation */

string operation = argv[2];

if(operation != "-t" || operation != "-r")
{
    cout << "Something is not right";
}

}
```

If I do: `cout << operation;` then the result would be: `-t` when passing -t through when I run the applications.

Could anyone suggest where I could be going wrong?

UPDATE:

I will pass in these arguments:

`./main something.wav -t`

I am expecting the if statement:

```
if(operation != "-t" || operation != "-r")
{
    cout << "Something is not right";
}
```

To return negative since the value I have entered is -t

Comment: Huh? What arguments are you passing, what output are you expecting, and what are you getting?

Comment: Your test here is wrong: `if(operation != "-t" || operation != "-r")` - it should be: `if(operation != "-t" && operation != "-r")`

Comment: @PaulR Thank you. Can you put that as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: @downvoter - Can you please tell me why my post was downvoted? Put a short answer and TELL ME WHY instead of just down-voting it..

Comment: @Phorce: I didn't downvote, but people do tend to downvote "find the trivial error in my code even without me telling you what I expected it to do and what it did" type questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(operation != "-t" || operation != "-r")
{
    cout << "Something is not right";
}
```

Whatever the operation is, it must be either not equal to "-t" or not equal to "-r", so this will *always* print "Something is not right".

> I am expecting the if statement:
>   To return negative since the value I have entered is -t

The second half of the OR is true. An OR is true if either the first half OR the second half is true. You want `((operation != "-t") && (operation != "-r"))`. That way, the `if` will only fire if the input isn't -t *and* it's also not -r.